# Learning to build band matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to build square [band matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banded_matrix) using [`blkdiag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/blkdiag.html) or [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html), but can't figure out how. I find the documentation for `spdiags` a bit confusing, and am not sure I can build these matrices in a simple call to `blkdiag`.

I would like to build a square band matrix from two parameters:

- The width of the band
- Matrix size

For example:

```
band_width = 2;
matrix size = 9;
```

Result:

```
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Is it your intent to create a matrix of ones and zeroes as in your example, or are you going to be filling diagonals with different values?

Comment: Thanks @gnovice. With ones and zeroes as in the example, but the band with and matrix size can vary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tricky one-line way to create a matrix like this is with convolution:

```
M = sign(conv2(eye(matrix_size),ones(band_width+1),'same'));
```

An [identity matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eye.html) is created of the given size, then [convolved in 2-D](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html) with a [square matrix of ones](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ones.html), then converted to zeroes and ones by taking the [sign](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sign.html).

The above is fine for making relatively small non-sparse matrices. For larger matrices the convolution may get expensive and you would probably want to represent the result as a [sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) instead. Here is how you can do this in a general way using [SPDIAGS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html):

```
M = spdiags(ones(matrix_size,2*band_width+1),...
            -band_width:band_width,matrix_size,matrix_size);
```

Comment: That's a great trick! I find this solution very elegant actually.