# Define matrix in MATLAB of GF(2)

Tags: matrix, matlab

I have never use MATLAB before but I have to do one operation that deal with matrix of 25(row) x 25(col). So I don't want to do this by hand. So I have to use matlab.

I want to define matrix in MATLAB of GF(2) (the Galois field of order 2 is a mathematical structure called a field that provides a formal definition of arithmetic modulo two) .

Following is my 5x5 matrix for which I am getting null space from command null(MATRIX,'r')

```
1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
```

Following is my 6x6 matrix for which I am getting empty result when I tried the command null(MATRIX,'r')

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Can any body tell me what is the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have all the elements of the matrix written out like that, just write `A=[` then copy the matrix, then put `];`. For example, if you matrix was

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

then you can just do

```
A=[1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8 9];
```

Then to find the null space used `null(A)`.

Comment: No. I tried this. But this will not give me correct null space. Either  your suggested way of defining matrix is incorrect for Gf(2).

Comment: Try `null(A,'r')`. You can read more about `null` here: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/null.html?searchHighlight=null

Comment: David it's work just minor change result=mod(null(A),2). Thanks

Comment: result=mod(null(A,'r'),2).

Comment: I got one problem just edited the question. Please have a look and let me know if you can help me.

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28633-gfnull

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, can you just use the function "null" in matlab? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html

For the first part, perhaps this will help: [Learning to build band matrices in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756642/learning-to-build-band-matrices-in-matlab)

You're trying to make band matrix that also has ones on the diagonals up by five and down by five. To make those one, I think you can just do

```
[m,n] = size(A);
i = 1;
for j = 6:n
    A(i,j) = 1;
    i = i+1;
end
```

This will produce the upper diagonal. To do the lower, just do

```
j = 1;
for i = 6:n
    A(i,j) = 1;
    j = j+1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to construct such a band matrix is

A=toeplitz([1 1 0 0 0 0 1 zeros(1,18)])

My rule of thumb: every for-loop is a failure to use Matlab efficiently.