# 100x100 Matrix MATLAB coding

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to generate a 100x100 Matrix that is similar to this
whereby the first line and last line are different
and the middle ones are all the same but shifted along by 1.

Here is what I have for a 10x10 matrix:

```
>> A=[0.8 -0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
-0.3 0.5 -0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 -0.3 0.5 -0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 -0.3 0.5 -0.2 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 -0.3 0.5 -0.2 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 -0.3 0.5 -0.2 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 -0.3 0.5 -0.2 0 0;
 0 0 0 0 0 -0.3 0.5 -0.2 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.3 0.5 -0.2;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.3 0.7;]

B= [62; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 82]

>> solution=inv(A)*B
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: As a side note, using `solution=inv(A)*B` is less efficient and less stable than `solution=A\B`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called a [Band Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756642/learning-to-build-band-matrices-in-matlab) also see [this](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html)

```
n=10;
e=ones(n,1);
A=spdiags([-0.3*e 0.5*e -0.2*e],-1:1,n,n)
```

now this is a sparse Matrix, where the zeros are not stored which can improve storage and speed. If you want a full matrix, simply use `A=full(spdiags(...))`.

For `B` do:

```
B=ones(10,1)*0.8;
B(1) =62;
B(10)=82;
```

Comment: sorry I wanted B to go down in a column not a row
and what if I don't want 0 in the middle but let's say 0.8?

Answer (score 0):

code to create A is:

```
A = zeros(100);
A(1,1:2) = [0.8 -0.2];
for i = 2:99
    A(i,i-1:i+1) = [-0.3 0.5 -0.2];
end
A(100,99:100) = [-0.3 0.7];
```

you can then do B with the same template.

Comment: how do you do B?
coz it's a 1x10 matrix?

Comment: B = zeros(8,1);
    B(1) = 62; B(10) = 82;

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

```
%%// Only this part would change when you go from your sample size of 10 to 100
N = 100; 

A = zeros(N); %%// Initialize
A(1:size(A,1)+1:end) = 0.5; %%// Diagonal values
A(2:size(A,1)+1:end) = -0.3;%%// Left-to-diagonal values
A(size(A,1)+1:size(A,1)+1:end) = -0.2;%%// Right-to-diagonal values
A([1 end]) = [0.8 0.7]; %% Different scalars at the top and end
```

**Approach 2:**

```
N = 100; %%// Size of matrix

L = -0.3; %%// Left to diagonal values
D = 0.5;  %%// Diagonal values
R = -0.2;  %%// Right to diagonal values

A = D*diag(ones(N,1)) + R*diag(ones(N-1,1),1) + L*diag(ones(N-1,1),-1);
A([1 end]) = [0.8 0.7]; %% Different scalars at the top and end
```